# Keyboard shortcut to navigate between IntelliJ views

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, there are some underlined numbers on the side menus :

- 1: Project
- 7: Structure

Like below :

[image: Side menus]

So there is probably a keyboard shortcut which allows to navigate from one view to another by just entering the view number.

I tried the different digits with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> etc but could not find the right shortcut.

How can I easily navigate between those views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortcut is `Alt + [number]`

ps. There's a plugin `force-shortcuts` if you wanna replace your mouse click actions with shortcuts (https://github.com/treytrahin/force-shortcuts-intellij-plugin). It's super annoying but you learn really fast. And by the way here are such plugins to most editors and IDEs.

Comment: It does not work for me. Which OS are you using? Maybe Alt+ number is already assigned to something else on my Linux Mint...

Comment: Hmmm, actually, no, it comes from my AZERTY keyboard. `Alt + 1` is not reachable from this keyboard. When I hit `Alt + 1`, it is considered as `Alt + &` as you can see on this [image](http://static.ccm2.net/ccm.net/faq/images/0-Vuskup12-azerty-s-.png).

Comment: Hence, you are right (I accept the answer as soon as I can). And it means that AZERTY keyboard users must redefine the shortcuts.

Comment: No. If I try to add this shortcut, I can see that it is considered as `alt + shift + &`.

Answer (score 1):

`ALT+F1` opens a window where you can choose one of the views by pressing the corresponding number.

*Info*: It actually opens the selected file in the selected view - which is not that bad maybe - but not 100% what you want?

Also there are cool things like pressing *C* to open a file chosen in Project Explorer directly in Explorer for example.

[image]